# Bandwidth estimation with multiple TCP connections

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, bandwidth

I have a client which issues parallel requests for data from a server. Each request uses a separate TCP connection. I would like to estimate the available throughput (bandwidth) based on the received data.

I know that for one connection TCP connection I can do so by dividing the amount of data the has been download by the duration of time it took to download the data. But given that there are multiple concurrent connections, would it be correct to sum up all the data that has been downloaded by the connections and divide the sum by the duration between sending the first request and the arrival time of the last byte (i.e., the last byte of the download that finishes last)? Or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a rewrite of my previous answer, which was getting too messy]

There are two components that we want to measure in order to calculate throughput:  the total number of bytes transferred, and the total amount of time it took to transfer those bytes.  Once we have those two figures, we just divide the byte-count by the duration to get the throughput (in bytes-per-second).

Calculating the number of bytes transferred is trivial; just have each TCP connection tally the number of bytes it transferred, and at the end of the sequence, we add up all of the tallies into a single sum.

Calculating the amount of time it takes for a single TCP connection to do its transfer is likewise trivial:  just record the time (t0) at which the TCP connection received its first byte, and the time (t1) at which it received its last byte, and that connection's duration is (t1-t0).

Calculating the amount of time it takes for the aggregate process to complete, OTOH, is not so obvious, because there is no guarantee that all of the TCP connections will start and stop at the same time, or even that their download-periods will intersect at all.  For example, imagine a scenario where there are five TCP connections, and the first four of them start immediately and finish within one second, while the final TCP connection drops some packets during its handshake, and so it doesn't start downloading until 5 seconds later, and it also finishes one second after it starts.  In that scenario, do we say that the aggregate download process's duration was 6 seconds, or 2 seconds, or ???

If we're willing to count the "dead time" where no downloads were active (i.e. the time between t=1 and t=5 above) as part of the aggregate-duration, then calculating the aggregate-duration is easy:   Just subtract the smallest t0 value from the largest t1 value.  (this would yield an aggregate duration of 6 seconds in the example above).  This may not be what we want though, because a single delayed download could drastically reduce the reported bandwidth estimate.

A possibly more accurate way to do it would be say that the aggregate duration should only include time periods when at least one TCP download was active; that way the result does not include any dead time, and is thus perhaps a better reflection of the actual bandwidth of the network path.

To do that, we need to capture the start-times (t0s) and end-times (t1s) of all TCP downloads as a list of time-intervals, and then merge any overlapping time-intervals as shown in the sketch below.  We can then add up the durations of the merged time-intervals to get the aggregate duration.

[image: Sketch of example download set]

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for restructuring the answer and for the detailed explanation. That seems to be the right way to do it. And I believe that not counting the "dead time" is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a weighted average. Let B(n) be the bytes processed for connection 'n' and T(n) be the time required to process those bytes. The total throughput is:

```
double throughput=0;
for (int n=0; n<Nmax; ++n)
{
    throughput += B(n) / T(n);
}
throughtput /= Nmax;
```

Comment: I think dividing by the number of connections will give the wrong result -- it would give you the average bandwidth of a single TCP connection, whereas I think the poster wants to know the bandwidth used by the system as a whole.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, my goal is to estimate the end-to-end throughput of the path which is being used by multiple TCP connections (where all connections are between the same source and destination nodes).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, drop the /Nmax for total bandwidth. I gave  the average.